# Signin and signup process via SMS in Meteor

Tags: meteor, authentication, twilio, meteor-accounts

I need a SMS-authentication in my Meteor app.

Let's say I have a simple form (in React-style, because I'm using React in frontend):

```
<form onSubmit={ this.submitPhone() }>
  <input type='text' size='10' placeholder='Your phone here' />
  <input type='submit' value='Send me a code'/>
</form>
```

User enters his phone number and submits the form. After that SMS-code is sent to the entered number. And a new form appears:

```
<form onSubmit={ this.submitCode() }>
  <input type='text' size='5' placeholder='Enter code' />
  <input type='submit' value='Sign In'/>
</form>
```

If user enters his code correctly, then Meteor should know that the user is logged in (with some _id, I think). If the code is not correct, then an error message is shown.

I found Twilio service and this [package](https://github.com/DispatchMe/meteor-accounts-sms) and it looks like it is exactly what I need. But I don't know how to use it at all.

I have tried only Meteor's default Accounts UI way of authentication a few months ago in the tutorials, but actually I don't know how to do such things, especially via SMS. I don't need such things like roles in my app, I even don't need usernames, passwords and e-mails. I just need to have a base of user `_id` and `phone`. So all I need is make user be able to sign in (first time signin is signup in this way).

Thank for your help, a detailed answer is really what I need this time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to install one of the following packages:

- [http](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/http) (To call the Twilio API directly from your methods) or,
- [accolver:twilio-meteor](https://atmospherejs.com/accolver/twilio-meteor) (You can try using the services this package provides off of the official [Twilio-Node Helper Library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node))

Next, you should also install the [okland:accounts-phone](https://atmospherejs.com/okland/accounts-phone) package to help enable login via phone number. Their [GitHub](https://github.com/okland/accounts-phone/) provides easy to follow instructions on how to set it up.

**Password**

I would strongly recommend creating user accounts with a password, along with the phone number, since it is a good security feature to have, and is also required by default on Meteor Accounts package.

**Verification Process**

I will be giving an example using *server-side Meteor methods*, for frontend you can write your React handlers accordingly.

This example will be using the HTTP package, in your code you can modify it to include other wrapper packages like twilio-meteor if you wish.

***Step 1:*** 
Register your user and send verification SMS.

*createNewUser method:*

```
'createNewUser': function (password, phoneNumber) {
    var min = 10000;
    var max = 99999;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

    var verified = Meteor.users.find({username: phoneNumber}).fetch();
    if (verified.length > 0) {
        if (verified.length == 1 && verified[0].profile.isMobileVerified == 'NO') {
            Meteor.users.remove({username: phoneNumber});
            var user = {username: phoneNumber, password: password, profile: { randomSms: random, isMobileVerified: 'NO' }};
            Meteor.call("sendSMS", random, phoneNumber);
            Accounts.createUser(user);
            return returnSuccess('Successfully created', phoneNumber);
        } else {
            return returnFaliure('Mobile number already exists', phoneNumber);
        }
    } else {
        var user = {username: phoneNumber, password: password, profile: { randomSms: random, isMobileVerified: 'NO' }};
        Meteor.call("sendSMS", random, phoneNumber);
        Accounts.createUser(user);
        return returnSuccess('Successfully created', phoneNumber);
    }    
},
```

*sendSMS method:*

```
'sendSMS': function (code, mobile) {
    console.log(mobile);
    HTTP.call(
        "POST",
        'https://api.twilio.com/{yyyy-dd-mm}/Accounts/' + 
        '{TWILIO_APPKEY}' + '/SMS/Messages.json', {
            params: {
                From: '+11234567890',
                To: mobile,
                Body: "Greetings! Your OTP is " + code
            },
            auth: '{TWILIO_APPKEY}' + ':' + '{TWILIO_PASSWORD}'
        },
        // Print error or success to console
        function (error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
            else {
                console.log('SMS sent successfully.');
            }
        }
    );
}
```

***Step 2:***
Ask user for verification code and check code input by user

*verifySMS method:*

```
'verifySMS': function (code, userid) {
    console.log(userid);
    var sms = Meteor.users.findOne({username: userid}).profile.randomSms;
    if (sms == code) {
        Meteor.users.update({username: userid}, {
            $set: {"profile.isMobileVerified": "YES", "profile.randomSms": "--"}
        });
        return returnSuccess("Yes");
    } else {
        return returnSuccess("No");
    }
},
```

***Step 3:***
From your React code handling, if code matches, approve the user, else display appropriate error message.

---

**UPDATE to handle specific use case by OP:** 
(Example indicative of React code)

To have the user authenticated via SMS OTP code everytime before login, you will need to use the sendSMS method every time the user tries to login, update it in a collection of stored AuthCodes, verify the code each time, and handle case accordingly.

**React Form:**
You will need to render a form something like this inside your react JSX code container.

```
<form className="new-task" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} >
    <input
        type="text"
        ref="phoneNumberInput"
        placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
    />
</form>
```

Write React function to login user:

```
handleSubmit() {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Find the phone number field via the React ref
    const phoneNumber = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.phoneNumberInput).value.trim();
    Meteor.call('sendAuthCode', Meteor.userId(), phoneNumber, function(error, result) {
        // Show a popup to user that code has been sent
    });    
}
```

Then, similar as above, create another form to have the user input the code sent to them, and send that to server for verification, e.g.

```
handleAuthCheck() {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Find the phone number field via the React ref
    const phoneNumber = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.phoneNumberInput).value.trim();
    const code = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.codeInput).value.trim();
    Meteor.call('verifyAuthCode', Meteor.userId(), phoneNumber, code, function(error, result) {
        // handle result accordingly
        // you need to decide how you are going to login user 
        // you can create a custom module for that if you need to
    });    
}
```

**AuthCodes Collection:**
You will need to define a collection in a file and export it, so that it can be imported where needed.

```
export const AuthCodes = new Mongo.Collection('authcodes');
```

**Meteor server methods:**

*Send SMS:*

```
'sendAuthCode': function(userId, phoneNumber) {
    var min = 10000;
    var max = 99999;
    var code = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    Meteor.call("sendSMS", code, phoneNumber);
    AuthCodes.insert({ 
        userId: userId, 
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber, 
        code: code 
    });    
}
```

*Verify Code:*

```
'verifyAuthCode': function(userId, phoneNumber, code) {
    var authCode = AuthCodes.findOne({ phoneNumber: phoneNumber, code: code })   // You can also add userId check for added verification
    if(typeof authCode !== "undefined" && authCode) {
        // verification passed
        return true;
    } else {
        // verification failed
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! I think that it is not what I am looking for, if I understand your code correctly. This methods provides me a way to 1) create a user with PhoneNumber, Password and boolean field isVerified. And with these methods I can verify user's number for the only one time - when this user has isVerified = false. And after that user can only log in to my site with his phone and password. Sorry, if I don't understand correct. BUT I need to "Send sms -> Verify the code -> User logged in" every time that user want to log in. How can I achieve that?

Comment: okland/accounts-phone gives me a way to create a user with phone number AND PASSWORD, then verify its number once (first time) and then this user has to log in via its phone and password. but I need to sign in each time via new sms code. Thank you for your help!

Comment: In that case you can just use the sendSMS method everytime the user tries to login, update it in a collection of stored randomNumbers, verify the code each time, and handle case accordingly. Does this satisfy the use case?

Comment: I think yes! It looks like thing I want to achieve. But unfortunately for me I understand this case in general terms, not in details sufficient for writing code for myself. If you don't mind, can you please show me how to do that? You can post your answer not necessarily this moment, but when you ll have a free couple of minutes! the second part of this comment is about accounts-sms package (a link in the question), this package does all that work, doesn't it? but I can not find any piece of information about how to use it... thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hope for your answer! I m trying to achieve this all day long

Comment: Can you please update your question with the code that you have tried so far to achieve your use case? I will try to get back to it and help you out soon.

Comment: okay, I get it, I will update this question with my code soon!

Comment: I have updated the answers with the algorithm needed for your use case. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I saw the answer once I wrote a comment. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Nivedit, appreciate the detailed answer you offer here! Can I send you a t-shirt to say thanks for helping out in the Twilio-tagged community? Send an email to mspeir@twilio.com for details.